# Как сохранить иконку при переводе из PyQt в exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

В общем есть файл main.ui переведенный в main.py и скомпилированный в main.exe с помощью pyinstaller. Но проблема в том что иконка в приложении .exe не отображается. Я знаю как поставить иконку в pyinstaller но это не решает мою проблему, внутри самой программы иконка должна отображаться. Как это защить?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста `main.py` для демонстрации вашей проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Ребят.Прошу ВНИМАНИЯ. Если пишите программы через QtDesigner и потом в итоге их переводите в exe. Все файлы которые нужны программе сохраняйте в директорию с программой!

Comment: Да, такие вопросы уже обсуждались.